# React - keep child state whenever render list by Parent

Tags: reactjs, components

I am a beginner in React. 
I need a parent's state keeps a list of cards(as children),
and every child also has its own state.
My problem is the child will be unmounted whenever the parent add a card.

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zrz4qw3yv3) is a simple rebuild for my situation

---

I have tried :

1. keep one more state in parents:

but the card is dynamic increasing and it will encounter state asynchronous issues that might use Redux to solve it... I don't want to use Redux here.

### -

Need some advice for this, thanks a lot.

---

Edit : (more detail of what I want to do )

1.Parent can add different card in the list by the button on top.

2.Child has its own state, in this example I can click the button on the left to change the child's state.

Problem : the children state will back to initial state:1 whenever I add a new card... I need them keep the original state.

Comment: since u r rendering the children from parent, i guess it should be a list. In this case, as long as you don't change the key on each render, the component will not be unmounted. instead only new props will be sent to the already mounted component.

Comment: Can you paste your code (parent and child components) here. It's hard to understand What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @SangHuynh thanks for replying.
I did show the similar code above using CodeSandBox 
here is the [link] (https://codesandbox.io/s/zrz4qw3yv3) 
I will edit the question so you can understand what I want to do, thanks.

Comment: @Panther , but it seems not work.
Like the example I showed above,whenever I add  a new item , the state(counter) restart again

Comment: i modified your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9qmj3oo21y) and the child component did keep its state on subsequent re-render. Checkout if my understanding is correct.!

Comment: @Panther Close, but I am trying to add different components... I think it will face new issues... any ideas? I will try as well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the child component is belongs to the parent. Therefore, whenever you update parent state, It'll re-render parent component => the child will re-init again. To avoid this problem by NOT using redux or something else to manage your state.

You should init some value in parent component then pass it to child as prop. Then that prop will Not be affected when your parent state is changed. => Your problem will be solved.